# Unit testing static method- GsonSerializer

Tags: java, junit, mockito, gson

I need to junit test a piece of code, but the GsonConverter it calls from different class is in static method that i cannot change. I haven't a clue how to proceed as i cant mock it due to it being static.

```
public String fetchEntity(Object retValue, Object[] args) {

        String refDet= null;
        List<Details> updatedDetails = null;
        if (retValue != null && retValue instanceof List && ((List) retValue).stream()
                .noneMatch((o -> !(o instanceof Details)))) {
            updatedDetails = (List<Details>) retValue;  
        } else {
            logger.warn("Error");
            return null;    
        }
        try {
            refDet= GsonConverter.serialize(updatedDetails );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn("Error updatedDetails ");   
        } 
        return refDet;
    }
```

Here is the class with static methods

```
class GsonConverter{
public static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder()
 .registerTypeAdapter(DateTime.class, (JsonDeserializer<DateTime>) (dateTime, type, context) -> ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().parseDateTime(dateTime.getAsString()))
            .create();

    public static String serialize(Object o) {
        return GSON.toJson(o);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing would be to hide the direct use of GsonConverter behind an object instance. Perhaps something like:

```
interface JsonMapper {
  String toJsonString(Object o);
}

class GsonJsonMapper implements JsonMapper {
  String toJsonString(Object o) {
    return GsonConverter.serialize(o);
  }
}
```

Now in your original code, depend on the interface (JsonMapper) but instantiate it as an GsonJsonMapper (ideally using a dependency injection framework like Guice or Spring).

```
// declare an instance of type JsonMapper
private JsonMapper mapper;

public String fetchEntity(Object retValue, Object[] args) {
  // skip the first part ...
  try {
    // use the mapper
    refDet = mapper.serialize(updatedDetails );
  } catch (Exception e) {
    logger.warn("Error updatedDetails ");   
  } 
  return refDet;
}
```

Now you have the ability to mock out the JsonMapper interface.

You will often encounter this type of situation -- code that was not written to be testable often must change in order to add tests. Which is why many developers practice TDD, or at least write unit tests immediately after writing the new code.